# Defining SQL parameters for INSERT Statement in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have created a parameterized SQL insert query and I have made a mistake somewhere. I kept getting a message that values would be truncated, so, during troubleshooting I reduced the query to only fields that required values (NULLs not allowed), and the insert statement completed.

I check the table, and I see my parameter names inserted, not the values they should be pulling from the form's textboxes.

Obviously I am calling my parameters incorrectly but I just can't figure out where I have gone wrong. I am hoping you all can help me.

Thanks in advance!

**NOTE:** Yes, I know there are more parameters than what I am using in the `INSERT` string.  I have intentionally cut down the values used for troubleshooting.

Thanks again!

```
try {
    string InsertString = @"INSERT INTO Item.Itemtable
        (ItemNumber, ItemDesc, RatioToOriginalItemNumber, OriginalItemNumber, EntreeCount, ItemType, ProteinBeverage)
        Values(@ItemNumberValue, '@ItemDescValue', @RatioToOriginalItemNumberValue, @OriginalItemNumberValue, @EntreeCountValue, '@ItemTypeValue', @ProteinBeverageValue)";
    SqlCommand InsertNewItem = new SqlCommand(InsertString, PmixWriter);
    //Define Insert Parameters
    SqlParameter @ItemNumberValue = InsertNewItem.Parameters.Add("@ItemNumberValue", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
    SqlParameter @ItemDescValue = InsertNewItem.Parameters.Add("@ItemDescValue", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
    SqlParameter @ItemTypeValue = InsertNewItem.Parameters.Add("@ItemTypeValue", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
    SqlParameter @ProteinBeverageValue = InsertNewItem.Parameters.Add("@ProteinBeverageValue", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
    SqlParameter @IsCouponValue = InsertNewItem.Parameters.Add("@IsCouponValue", System.Data.SqlDbType.Char, 3);
    SqlParameter @EntreeCountValue = InsertNewItem.Parameters.Add("@EntreeCountValue", System.Data.SqlDbType.Real);
    SqlParameter @BevCountValue = InsertNewItem.Parameters.Add("@BevCountValue", System.Data.SqlDbType.TinyInt);
    SqlParameter @OriginalItemNumberValue = InsertNewItem.Parameters.Add("@OriginalItemNumberValue", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
    SqlParameter @RatioToOriginalItemNumberValue = InsertNewItem.Parameters.Add("@RatioToOriginalItemNumberValue", System.Data.SqlDbType.TinyInt);
    SqlParameter @FPBeverageCountValue = InsertNewItem.Parameters.Add("@FPBeverageCountValue", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
    SqlParameter @FPBeverageEntreeCountValue = InsertNewItem.Parameters.Add("@FPBeverageEntreeCountValue", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
    SqlParameter @FoodCostValue = InsertNewItem.Parameters.Add("@FoodCostValue", System.Data.SqlDbType.Money);

    //Assign and covert values to the stated SQL parameters.
    @ItemNumberValue.Value = Convert.ToInt32(ItemNumberBox.Text);
    @ItemDescValue.Value = ItemDescBox.Text;
    @ItemTypeValue.Value = ItemTypeBox.Text;
    @ProteinBeverageValue.Value = ProteinBevBox.Text;
    @IsCouponValue.Value = IsCouponBox.Text;
    @EntreeCountValue.Value = Convert.ToInt32(EntreeCountBox.Text);
    @BevCountValue.Value = Convert.ToInt32(BevCountBox.Text);
    @OriginalItemNumberValue.Value = Convert.ToInt32(OriginalItemNumBox.Text);
    @RatioToOriginalItemNumberValue.Value = Convert.ToInt32(RatioBox.Text);
    @FPBeverageCountValue.Value = Convert.ToInt32(FPBevBox.Text);
    @FPBeverageEntreeCountValue.Value = Convert.ToInt32(FPBevEntreeBox.Text);
    @FoodCostValue.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(0.00);

    InsertNewItem.ExecuteNonQuery();
} catch (SqlException) {
    throw;   
}
```

Comment: Without the table definition, this question isn't answerable. Truncation probably indicates that you're trying to store strings longer than the field in the db. For instance storing "db" in an `nvarchar(1)` would give you this warning.

Comment: Are you sure that the values passed in the `VarChar` parameters don't exceed the declared length of 100?  Do they match the column definitions in the table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your INSERT statement, remove the single quotes from @ItemDescValue and @ItemTypeValue parameters.  They are currently being inserted as literal values otherwise.

Comment: Took a decent amount of squinting, that's for sure!

Comment: I should also add that this sort of situation is one of the reasons inline queries are generally frowned upon.  An IDE for SQL (instead of strings in code) would have made this pretty easy to solve.

Comment: So single quotes are not needed for text strings when using parameters this way?

Comment: Correct.  The parameter type is what specifies what the value will be treated as.  Single quotes allow you to "force-feed" string values, so to speak.

Comment: Thanks for everything guys.  I appreciate the help.